# Вывести на карту несколько открытых балунов

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Блин я тупой. Или это не возможно сделать? Как вывести на карту несколько балунов в открытом виде? Всегда выводится только последний

У гугла как то все просто и легко это делается[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как тоже самое у вас это сделать?

Вроде конструкция

```
myMap.balloon.open([67,33], 'балун2', {closeButton: false  });
myMap.balloon.open([68,34], 'балун1', {closeButton: false  });
```

Все должна решать, но нет....

Comment: ну раз помощи нет, остаюсь на гугле :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Балуны в [JS API Яндекса](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/) не предполагается выводить во множественном числе. Их реализация в сервисе так и задумывалась, как единичный объект на карте.

Задачу следует решать через [HTML-макет меток](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/placemark_shape). Меток же на карте можно отобразить одновременно значительное количество.