# Как в yandex map api автоматом открывать balloon у MultiRoute?

Tags: api, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Всем привет! Сделал скрипт который при вводе адреса прокладывались 3 маршрута к ближайшим меткам. Никак не могу понять как автоматом открывать баул у MultiRoute. Пробовал и через events.fire('balloonopen'); ничего не помогает.
Вот демо https://dev5.vh448018.eurodir.ru/

```js
 ymaps.ready(function () {

    var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
                    center: [37.617633, 55.755820],
                    zoom: 8,
                    controls: ['zoomControl', 'fullscreenControl', 'routeButtonControl'],
                },
                {
                    searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
                });

    var pinsJson, searchGeoPoision, objcsJson = [];

    function findClosestObjects () {

        // Найдем в выборке кафе, ближайшее к найденной станции метро,
        // и откроем его балун.
        //pinsJson.getClosestTo(searchGeoPoision.get(0)).balloon.open();
        
        // Будем открывать балун кафе, который ближе всего к месту клика
        /*myMap.events.add('click', function (event) {
            pinsJson.getClosestTo(event.get('coords')).balloon.open();
        });*/

        console.log(searchGeoPoision.get(0).geometry.getCoordinates());


    }

        //console.log(objcsJson);

        pinsJson = ymaps.geoQuery({
            type: 'FeatureCollection',
              "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": 0,
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          37.49736,
          55.824804
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "description": "Москва, Ленинградское шоссе, 16",
        "iconCaption": "Point 1",
        "marker-color": "#1bad03"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": 1,
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          37.605939,
          55.622609
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "description": "Москва, Кировоградская улица, 14",
        "iconCaption": "Point 2",
        "marker-color": "#ffff00"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": 2,
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          37.606514,
          55.883742
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "description": "Москва, улица Плещеева, 4",
        "iconCaption": "Point 3",
        "marker-color": "#0000ff"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": 3,
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          37.495994,
          55.693505
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "description": "Россия, Москва, улица Раменки, 3",
        "iconCaption": "Point 4",
        "marker-color": "#000000"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": 4,
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          37.409253,
          55.759238
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "description": "Москва, Осенний бульвар, 12",
        "iconCaption": "Point 5",
        "marker-color": "#ff0000"
      }
    }
  ]
        }).addToMap(myMap);

    // С помощью обратного геокодирования найдем метро "Кропоткинская".
    //searchGeoPoision = ymaps.geoQuery(ymaps.geocode([37.603423, 55.744828], {kind: 'metro'})).then(findClosestObjects);

    /*
    * Search
    */
    var suggestView = new ymaps.SuggestView('suggest'),
        routeIndex1,
        routeIndex2,
        routeIndex3;

    $('#searchYanMap').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var addr = $('#suggest').val();

        if( addr != '' ) {
            var myGeocoder = ymaps.geocode(addr, { results: 1 });

            myGeocoder.then(
                function (res) {
                    var cord = res.geoObjects.get(0).geometry.getCoordinates();

                    // console.log(cord[0]);
                    // console.log(cord[1]);

                    searchGeoPoision = ymaps.geoQuery(ymaps.geocode(cord, {kind: 'metro'})).then(function() {
                        /*var nearTips = pinsJson.getClosestTo(searchGeoPoision.get(0));
                        var nearTipsCord = nearTips.geometry.getCoordinates();
                            nearTips.balloon.open();*/


                        var sortedByPolyline = pinsJson.sortByDistance(cord);

                        // console.log(sortedByPolyline.get(0).geometry.getCoordinates());
                        // console.log(sortedByPolyline.get(1).geometry.getCoordinates());
                        // console.log(sortedByPolyline.get(3).geometry.getCoordinates());

                        var nearTips1     = sortedByPolyline.get(0),
                            nearTipsCord1 = nearTips1.geometry.getCoordinates(),
                            nearTips2     = sortedByPolyline.get(1),
                            nearTipsCord2 = nearTips2.geometry.getCoordinates(),
                            nearTips3     = sortedByPolyline.get(2),
                            nearTipsCord3 = nearTips3.geometry.getCoordinates();

                            // nearTips1.balloon.open();
                            // nearTips2.balloon.open();
                            // nearTips3.balloon.open();

                        //var tt = ;
                        

                        if(routeIndex1) {
                            myMap.geoObjects.remove(routeIndex1);
                            myMap.geoObjects.remove(routeIndex2);
                            myMap.geoObjects.remove(routeIndex3);
                        }

                        var balloonLayout1 = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
                            "<div class='route-balloon'>" +
                            '<a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>' +
                            "<span class='title'>{{ properties.pinsTitle }}<span>{{ properties.pinsDesc }}</span></span>" +
                            "Расстояние: " +
                            "<i>{{ properties.distance.text }}</i>,<br />" +
                            "Время в пути: " +
                            "<i>{{ properties.duration.text }} (без учета пробок) </i>" +
                            "</div>", {
                                build: function () {
                                    this.constructor.superclass.build.call(this);
                                    this._$element = $('.route-balloon', this.getParentElement());
                                    this._$element.find('.close')
                                        .on('click', $.proxy(this.onCloseClick, this));

                                    console.log(this);
                                },
                                onCloseClick: function (e) {
                                    e.preventDefault();
                                    this.events.fire('userclose');
                                },
                            }
                        );

                        //searchGeoPoision = ymaps.geoQuery(ymaps.geocode([37.603423, 55.744828], {kind: 'metro'})).then(findClosestObjects);

                        var multiRoute1 = new ymaps.multiRouter.MultiRoute({
                            // Точки маршрута. Точки могут быть заданы как координатами, так и адресом. 
                            referencePoints: [
                                nearTipsCord1,
                                cord
                            ],
                            params: {
                                results: 2,
                                  // Тип маршрута: на общественном транспорте.
                                routingMode: "auto",
                            },
                        }, {
                              // Автоматически устанавливать границы карты так,
                              // чтобы маршрут был виден целиком.
                              //boundsAutoApply: true,
                              routeStrokeColor: "000088",
                              routeActiveStrokeColor: "ff0000",
                              pinIconFillColor: "ff0000",
                              balloonLayout: balloonLayout1,
                              // Отключаем режим панели для балуна.
                              balloonPanelMaxMapArea: 0,
                              test: 11233
                        });

                        //console.log(multiRoute1.model);

                        //multiRoute1.model.events.fire('balloonopen');

                        //multiRoute1._data.properties._data.test = 1111;

                        


                        //multiRoute1.balloon.open();

                        //multiRoute1.events.fire(['balloonopen', 'click']);

                        //multiRoute1.events.add('click', this.up, this);

                        /*multiRoute1.properties.set({
                            test: nearTips1.properties._data.iconCaption,
                            test2: nearTips1.properties._data.balloonContent
                        });*/


                        var multiRoute2 = new ymaps.multiRouter.MultiRoute({   
                            // Точки маршрута. Точки могут быть заданы как координатами, так и адресом. 
                            referencePoints: [
                                nearTipsCord2,
                                addr
                            ],
                            params: {
                                  // Тип маршрута: на общественном транспорте.
                                  routingMode: "auto"  
                            }
                        }, {
                              // Автоматически устанавливать границы карты так,
                              // чтобы маршрут был виден целиком.
                              //boundsAutoApply: true
                              balloonLayout: balloonLayout1,
                              // Отключаем режим панели для балуна.
                              balloonPanelMaxMapArea: 0,
                        });

                        var multiRoute3 = new ymaps.multiRouter.MultiRoute({   
                            // Точки маршрута. Точки могут быть заданы как координатами, так и адресом. 
                            referencePoints: [
                                nearTipsCord3,
                                addr
                            ],
                            params: {
                                  // Тип маршрута: на общественном транспорте.
                                  routingMode: "auto",
                                  routeMarker: false,
                            }
                        }, {
                              // Автоматически устанавливать границы карты так,
                              // чтобы маршрут был виден целиком.
                              //boundsAutoApply: true
                              balloonLayout: balloonLayout1,
                              // Отключаем режим панели для балуна.
                              balloonPanelMaxMapArea: 0,
                        });

                        ymaps.vow.all([
                            multiRoute1,
                            multiRoute2,
                            multiRoute3
                        ]).spread(function (route1, route2, route3) {
                            var objectsLength = myMap.geoObjects.getLength();

                            myMap.geoObjects.add(route1);
                            myMap.geoObjects.add(route2);
                            myMap.geoObjects.add(route3);

                            routeIndex1 = route1;
                            routeIndex2 = route2;
                            routeIndex3 = route3;

                            multiRoute1.model.events.add("requestsuccess", function () {
                                var routes = multiRoute1.model.getRoutes();
                                routes[0].properties.set('pinsTitle', nearTips1.properties._data.iconCaption);
                                routes[0].properties.set('pinsDesc', nearTips1.properties._data.balloonContent);
                            });

                            multiRoute2.model.events.add("requestsuccess", function () {
                                var routes = multiRoute2.model.getRoutes();
                                routes[0].properties.set('pinsTitle', nearTips2.properties._data.iconCaption);
                                routes[0].properties.set('pinsDesc', nearTips2.properties._data.balloonContent);
                            });

                            multiRoute3.model.events.add("requestsuccess", function () {
                                var routes = multiRoute3.model.getRoutes();
                                routes[0].properties.set('pinsTitle', nearTips3.properties._data.iconCaption);
                                routes[0].properties.set('pinsDesc', nearTips3.properties._data.balloonContent);
                            });

                            // Авто маштабирование
                            myMap.setBounds(sortedByPolyline.slice(0, 3).getBounds(), {
                                checkZoomRange: true,
                                zoomMargin: [150, 0, 100, 0]
                            });

                        });
                    });
                }
            ); // End geocode
        } else {
            $('.wrap-suggest').addClass('empty');

            setTimeout(function() {
                $('.wrap-suggest').removeClass('empty');
            }, 2000);
        }
        
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <title>Map zavod</title>

    <style>
        #map {width: 100%;height: 700px;}
        #notice{display: none;}
        
        .wrap-suggest {transition: all 300ms linear;}
        .wrap-suggest.empty:after {
            content: 'Введите свой аддрес';
            font-size: 12px;
            transition: all 300ms linear;
            margin-top: 5px;
            display: table;
            color: red;
        }
        .wrap-suggest.empty #suggest {border-color: red;transition: all 300ms linear}

        .route-balloon {
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 4px 10px;
            /*height: 75px;*/
            position: relative;
            bottom: 0;
            left: -35px;
            transform: translateY(-100%);
            margin-top: -35px;
            width: 158px;
            font-size: 12px;
            line-height: 15px;
            color: #333333;
            text-align: left;
            vertical-align: middle;
            background-color: #fff;
            border-radius: 5px;
            font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
            position: relative;
            box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
        }

        .route-balloon .title{
            display: block;
            /*font-size: 12px;*/
            margin-bottom: 5px;
            font-weight: 700;
            color: #000;
        }

        .route-balloon .title span {
            display: block;
            font-weight: 400;
            font-size: 11px;
        }

        .route-balloon .close {
            position: absolute;
            right: 4px;
            top: 0;
        }
    </style>

    <script src="https://yastatic.net/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU&amp;coordorder=longlat&amp;apikey=04107d8c-9835-492a-b09d-5252ee96daca"></script>
    <script src="map.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="container">
        <!-- <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/services/constructor/1.0/js/?um=constructor%3A25f3d5740f5d5a1aff192d6e12801721c0d1e7d74f3573ea19754665c456a94c&amp;width=100%25&amp;height=657&amp;lang=ru_RU&amp;id=map&amp;scroll=true&amp;search=true&amp;apikey=04107d8c-9835-492a-b09d-5252ee96daca"></script> -->

        <form action="#" id="searchYanMap">
            <div class="form-group row">
               <label for="inputPassword" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label"><b>Введите свой аддрес</b></label>
               <div class="col-sm-7">
                <div class="wrap-suggest">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Напр.: Москва, ул. Никольская, 10" id="suggest" autocomplete="off">
                </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-2">
                  <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-ymap-search">Найти</button>
               </div>
             </div>
            <p id="notice">Адрес не найден</p>
         </form>
         <br>
        <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>

    


    
</body>
</html>
```

Можно ввести например этот адрес: Москва, Новогиреевская улица, 48a
Нужно чтобы при вводе адреса строился маршрут и автоматом открывался баул, результат должен быть такой
https://yadi.sk/i/XnwHuhIzidCMKw

Долго искал решение, но так и не нашел как это сделать. Если кто знает подскажите куда копать

Comment: В API Яндекс.Карт нельзя открыть несколько балунов одновременно, архитектурно балун может быть только один на карте. Вот тут был ответ на похожий вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1315020/273315

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий. 
Это не совсем то, в route можно открыть одновременно несколько баулов, если нажимать на красную пиктограмму. Меня интересует как сделать тригер на эту красную метку, где буква "А". Т.е. с имитировать клик на эту иконку